# Binomial distribution by row using R

Tags: r, simulation, distribution

There are two columns, ID and probability

```
        ID probability
        1  0.5
        2  0.8
        3  0.3
```

I would like to simulate the sickness status of each ID with 0 for healthy and 1 for sick. The probability of each ID getting sick is in the second column.

I have tried

```
df$sick <- rbinom(1,1,df$probability)
```

but I get either all zeros or ones. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try `rbinom(nrow(df), 1, df$probability)`. Since you are simulating ***only one*** random binomial number the entire column vector `sick` becomes equal to that number. You have to simulate `nrow(df)` numbers in order to get what you are after.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate if my IDs are sick/healthy, therefore chose the binomial distribution. So ID1 has a 50% chance of being sick, ID2 80% and so on. I will run the simulation a couple of hundred times and want to know how many times ID1 was sick/healthy (0/1). I know how to loop, but am having trouble allocating different outcome probabilities for each ID.

Comment: The argument `prob` is vectorized so you don't have to loop. Each of those 3 random numbers will be generated using a different `prob` (the values in your vector `df$probability`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is, that you only set `n` to 1, and so `rbinom` only return one value which is reused for all rows (by R's standard reuse rules). See `?rbinom`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "ID probability
    1  0.5
    2  0.8
    3  0.3")

df$sick <- rbinom(n = nrow(df), size = 1, prob = df$probability)
print(df)
#  ID probability sick
#1  1         0.5    1
#2  2         0.8    1
#3  3         0.3    0
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and the solution! It worked like a charm.